# Investigate Java.Lang.NullPointerException on a Codename One iOS app

Tags: codenameone

Today I tried to investigate this issue: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2975
I'm writing here to ask how I can find exactly what goes wrong. This bug is frustrating.

Basically, on iOS only, I have this error, that happens after some random app usage:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com_codename1_ui_Form.pointerReleased:3758
    at net_informaticalibera_cn1_simpleapi_OuterForm.pointerReleased:360
    at com_codename1_ui_Component.pointerReleased:4679
    at com_codename1_ui_Display.handleEvent:2289
    at com_codename1_ui_Display.edtLoopImpl:1214
    at com_codename1_ui_Display.mainEDTLoop:1132
    at com_codename1_ui_RunnableWrapper.run:120
    at com_codename1_impl_CodenameOneThread.run:176
    at java_lang_Thread.runImpl:153
```

I've overridden the `pointerReleased` method to see if `x` and `y` are acceptable values when the previous exception is thrown, it seems so:

```
@Override
    public void pointerReleased(int x, int y) {
        try {
            super.pointerReleased(x, y);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.p("OuterForm.pointerReleased ERROR, x->" + x + ", y->" + y + ", https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2975");
            Log.e(ex);
            SendLog.sendLogAsync();
        }
    }
```

Using that override, that is equivalent to the crash protection feature, after the first time that this exception happens the `TextArea` components are not more usable: the tap on them doesn't open the VKB.

In short, there is a `NullPointerException` inside the iOS port of `Form.pointerReleased`: how can I discover which line of that method throws the exception? I hope to find info that can help for the bug resolution.

Comment: I can run the app with Xcode, but I don’t know how to debug with issue

Comment: If you run it in the xcode debugger it should break on the exception line and give you the full stack trace.in the native code.

Comment: Hi Shai, unfortunately Xcode doesn't stop on the exception line, that's why I need a more elaborated suggestion about debugging this kind of issue. The native log produced by Xcode has the same stack trace that I reported here.

Comment: I found a solution to solve this issue without the need of Xcode. I added an answer to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the code of the method `public void pointerReleased(int x, int y)` of the class [`Form`](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/master/CodenameOne/src/com/codename1/ui/Form.java) is all inside a `try... finally`, that hides the actual cause of the exception.
To get the actual cause, I used the following override in the `BaseForm` class of my app, that extends `Form` and that I use as superclass for all other Forms:

```
@Override
    public void pointerReleased(int x, int y) {
        try {
            Component cmp = instance.getResponderAt(x, y);
            if (cmp != null) {
                cmp.pointerReleased(x, y);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.p("BaseForm.pointerReleased ERROR, x->" + x + ", y->" + y + ", https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2975");
            Log.e(ex);
            SendLog.sendLogAsync();
        }
    }
```

As expected, this gave me the actual cause of the bug, that was inside a lambda expression of a `TextArea` actionListener: more specifically, the issue was a `revalidate` on an `Container` reference that can be `null` in some circumstances (oddly, this happens only on iOS). After that, I removed the previous override (that broke some functionalities), I fixed my code preventing the `revalidate` on a `null` object (with an `if` condition) and the bug disappeared (I've done a test with a long usage of the app).