# Why is my app throwing NPE when pointing an item while textField is focused?

Tags: codenameone

Somewhere in our app, we have a form with a dynamic autocomplete textfield.
This form contains a textfield and a button to clear the textfield.
These elements are on the top of a container where we display elements matching the text.

We have an issue where a NPE without any details appears when we "click" on a button.
This only happens when a textfield is focused (with the virtual keyboard displayed).

Everything works fine on the simulator and on Android but not on iOS.

```
txtWho.addDataChangedListener(new DataChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void dataChanged(int type, int index) {
            //Button generation
            if(txtWho.getText().length() > 2){
                final SectorConvert sect = new SectorConvert();
                List<AutoComplete> results = AccessAutoComplete.getAutoCompleteSiteAndSector(txtWho.getText());
                ctrResultAutoComplete.removeAll();

                for(final AutoComplete ac : results){
                    //Si secteur
                    if(ac.getType().equals("sector")){
                        if(ac.getId() != null && !sect.getValue(ac.getId()).equals("")){
                            Button mbtnPro = new Button(sect.getValue(ac.getId()).toString());
                            mbtnPro.setUIID("mbtnPro");
                            mbtnPro.addActionListener(new ActionListener<ActionEvent>() {
                                @Override
                                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                                    Home home = new Home(sect.getValue(ac.getId()).toString(), searchWhere);
                                    home.show();
                                }
                            });
                            ctrResultAutoComplete.add(mbtnPro);
                        }
                    // Si pro
                    }else if(ac.getType().equals("site")){
                        if(ac.getId() != null && !ac.getResult().equals("")){
                            Button mbtnPro = new Button(ac.getResult());
                            Image photo = CalendoviaApp.res.getImage("placeholderProvider").scaled((int)(Display.getInstance().getDisplayWidth()*0.13),(int)(Display.getInstance().getDisplayWidth()*0.15));
                            mbtnPro.setIcon(photo);
                            mbtnPro.setUIID("mbtnPro");
                            mbtnPro.addActionListener(new ActionListener<ActionEvent>() {
                                @Override
                                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                                    FichePro fichePro = new FichePro(ac.getId(), ac.getResult(), null);
                                    fichePro.show();
                                }
                            });
                            ctrResultAutoComplete.add(mbtnPro);
                        }
                    }
                }
                revalidate();
            }else{
                ctrResultAutoComplete.removeAll();
            }
            //Fast Del
            if(txtWho.getText().trim().length()>0){
                txtWhoFastDel.setVisible(true);
                revalidate();

                txtWhoFastDel.addActionListener(new ActionListener<ActionEvent>() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                        ctrResultAutoComplete.removeAll();
                        txtWho.setText("");
                        txtWhoFastDel.setVisible(false);
                    }
                });
            }else{
                txtWhoFastDel.setVisible(false);
                revalidate();
            }
        }
    });
```

The text error is only "An internal application error occured: java.lang.NullPointerException: null" so i used BrowserStack to get more informations.
Here is some log from the error.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com_codename1_impl_ios_IOSImplementation_10.run:945
at com_codename1_ui_Display.processSerialCalls:1301
at com_codename1_ui_Display.edtLoopImpl:1244
at com_codename1_ui_Display.invokeAndBlock:1432
at com_codename1_impl_ios_IOSImplementation.editString:897
at com_codename1_impl_CodenameOneImplementation.editStringImpl:320
at com_codename1_ui_Display.editString:1716
at com_codename1_ui_Display.editString:1680
at com_codename1_ui_TextArea.editString:737
at com_codename1_ui_TextArea.pointerReleased:774
at com_codename1_ui_TextField.pointerReleased:1657
at com_codename1_ui_Form.pointerReleased:3654
at com_codename1_ui_Component.pointerReleased:4679
at com_codename1_ui_Display.handleEvent:2289
at com_codename1_ui_Display.edtLoopImpl:1214
at com_codename1_ui_Display.mainEDTLoop:1132
at com_codename1_ui_RunnableWrapper.run:120
at com_codename1_impl_Code<\M-b\M^@\M-&>

java.lang.NullPointerException
at com_codename1_ui_Form.pointerReleased:3758
at com_codename1_ui_Component.pointerReleased:4679
at com_codename1_ui_Display.handleEvent:2289
at com_codename1_ui_Display.mainEDTLoop:1132
at com_codename1_ui_RunnableWrapper.run:120
at com_codename1_impl_CodenameOneThread.run:176
at java_lang_Thread.runImpl:153
```

At this point, i don't really understand why this is happening.
The app used to work fine (last update on store was 2017) but not anymore.

Hoping someone could help me, i wish you all a great day.

Comment: Please file an issue on that. I think this is related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59698676/investigate-java-lang-nullpointerexception-on-a-codename-one-ios-app you can file an issue here: github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/